# VScode mix.exs error - Could not compile with “make”

Tags: visual-studio-code, elixir

### Background

I have an umbrella app where I am making a build for windows using bakeware:
https://github.com/bake-bake-bake/bakeware

I have followed the normal setup for windows:

```
choco install -y zstandard make mingw
```

I have installed elixir and erlang otp via their official website installers:

- https://elixir-lang.org/install.html#windows
- https://www.erlang.org/downloads

### Problem

I am able to run and do everything normally, but my VSCode marks my `mix.exs` file as a huge red error blob:

```
an exception was raised:
    ** (Mix.Error) Could not compile with "make" (exit status: 2).

        (mix 1.13.1) lib/mix.ex:515: Mix.raise/2
        (elixir_make 0.6.3) lib/mix/tasks/compile.make.ex:154: Mix.Tasks.Compile.ElixirMake.run/1
        (mix 1.13.1) lib/mix/task.ex:397: anonymous fn/3 in Mix.Task.run_task/3
        (mix 1.13.1) lib/mix/tasks/compile.all.ex:92: Mix.Tasks.Compile.All.run_compiler/2
        (mix 1.13.1) lib/mix/tasks/compile.all.ex:72: Mix.Tasks.Compile.All.compile/4
        (mix 1.13.1) lib/mix/tasks/compile.all.ex:59: Mix.Tasks.Compile.All.with_logger_app/2
        (mix 1.13.1) lib/mix/tasks/compile.all.ex:36: Mix.Tasks.Compile.All.run/1
        (mix 1.13.1) lib/mix/task.ex:397: anonymous fn/3 in Mix.Task.run_task/3ElixirLS
```

### Question

In Bakeware's page there is a section:

> Change the default `MAKE` environment variable used by `elixir_make` from `nmake` to `make` (set it permanently to get rid of the errors in VSCode)

- But how do I do this?
- Is something wrong with my VSCode setup?

Comment: Is it `make` in the path? If you just installed it, the sessions might need to be reloaded.

Comment: How do I add it to VSCode's path?

Comment: I have updated the question with more info. If I understand how to set up the system's var, it should be good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Answer

I was able to somehow fix the issue.
Bakeware, the dependency, **really** likes Powershell. But not any powershell. A powershell with admin rights.
To get rid of the warning one must perform the following steps while VSCode is **closed**:

1. Open Windows Powershell in admin mode
2. set `$env:CC="gcc"`
3. set `$env:MAKE="make"`
4. set `MIX_ENV` to something. It doesnt have to be `prod`, but since powershell does not set this value by default, you have to manually set it yourself. Before running tests, fetching dependencies or anything.
5. `mix deps.get`

After this, if you still get the red wall of death, trying deleting your `.elixir_ls` folder to force to go again.
Then open VSCode with `code .`

Hope it works for you, it did for me.
Trying this with any other terminal will result in seeing the red wall of death. According to my experiments, powershell is the only that works.

Answer (score 1):

The [`elixir_make` docs](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir_make/Mix.Tasks.Compile.ElixirMake.html) say to set the `make_executable` in your `mix.exs` to the `make` command installed on the system.

And then in your shell, either set the environment variables the [Windows Way](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/windows-set-environment-variable) (If you already set the environment variables but they aren't taking, you may need to restart your terminal or VS Code), or if you're using `bash`, you can put them in your `.bash_profile` as the [`bakeware` docs](https://github.com/bake-bake-bake/bakeware#building-on-windows) show.

Command Prompt:

```
set MAKE=make
set CC=gcc
```

or MinGW

```
export MAKE=make
export CC=gcc
mix release
```

Comment: I have set up windows system vars using this tutorial: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/machine-learning/oml4r/1.5.1/oread/creating-and-modifying-environment-variables-on-windows.html#GUID-DD6F9982-60D5-48F6-8270-A27EC53807D0 and I changed my `mix.exs` file accordingly. Now I get another error: `Could not compile with "C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin\make.exe" (exit status: 2).`